# How do you suppress .html from the URLs of static HTML files with Cheyenne?

Tags: url-rewriting, rebol, cheyenne

I'm using [Cheyenne v0.9](http://cheyenne-server.org/) and would like to serve static HTML files as `text/html`, but I don't want the URLs to contain the `.html` extension. Is there a way to do this without using CGI or some other dynamic processor?

For example:

```
/path/to/example.org/web-root/about.html
```

To be reached using:

```
http://example.org/about
```

The Apache equivalent 'ReWrite' would be something like:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html [L]
```

Comment: Not exactly what you want but you could do that by using on-status-code [404 rewrite.rsp] config parameter. And inside rewrite.rsp just forward the request to *.html if file exists or show your 404 page if not.

Comment: @endo64 Aye, that's a bit of a hack. Cheyenne should (not that Apache is any better) have a way of mapping a canonical url to a static resource, ideally tied to the 'Accept' header...

Answer (score 5):

you can build a very simple mod which does this...

save the following as cheyenne/mods/mod-auto-ext.r

```
REBOL []

install-HTTPd-extension [
    name: 'mod-auto-ext

    order: [url-translate   first]

    auto-ext: '.html ; use whatever automatic extension you want!

    url-translate: func [req /local cfg domain ext][
        unless req/in/ext [
            req/in/ext: auto-ext
            append req/in/target req/in/ext
        ]

        ; allow other mods to play with url (changing target path for example)
        return none
    ]
]
```

then add your module within your httpd.cfg like so :

```
modules [
    auto-ext   ;<----- put it as first item in list, whatever mods you are using.

    userdir
    internal
    extapp    
    static
    upload
    expire  
    action
    ;fastcgi
    rsp
    ssi
    alias
    socket
]
```

restart cheyenne and voila!

If you look at the source for other mods, you can VERY easily setup a keyword for use in the httpd.cfg file in order to setup the auto-ext variable within the mod.

Comment: To clarify (and I should've put this in my question), if there is no HTML file associated with a given URL, will it still pass through to the regular 404 handler?

Comment: Be worth exploring how to make this work in conjunction with the Accept header also...

Comment: yes it would generate a 404 handler.  all we do is change the target (server side resource) the url refers to.